# The size of data types in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Beginner in programming here. The maximum integer a C++ short data type can hold is 32767. But can someone explain and enlighten me on this one?

```
short x = 32768;
```

The result is this:

```
-32768
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: In the dupe, the accepted answer makes specific assumptions, which are not guaranteed, about location of sign bit, etc.   So it is not actually correct in the context of standard C or C++.   Some of the other answers are better in this regard.

Comment: It's weird how all this stuff turns out in reality. An integer type has a fixed minimum size, but no fixed maximum. It just can't be larger than the next bigger size. `short` is no smaller than 16 bits and no larger than `int`. Which could also be 16 bits. Or it could be 512 bits. Does this happen in real life? Rarely, but yes. My old friend the classic Cray defined all of the integer types, `char` on up,  to be the same size.

Comment: @user4581301 I heard something similar about C40 signal processors that `char` is 32 bit there (to force proper alignment) ...though it's roundabout 25 years ago. ;-)